# Exception in thread "main" Session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 81

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using same Chrome Driver 81.0.4044.20
[image]

Still throwing same error even after updating the chrome drivers for the the version needed

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your question and paste the errors in the question instead of using images.

Comment: Update chromedriver version as for your current Google chrome version.

Comment: https://chromedriver.chromium.org

You should use correct chrome driver version according to your chrome browser version